# modify the row index of list in R

Tags: r, indexing

content is a list. I used `rbind()` to bind colNames and record1 in row direction. But the index the row of content are colNames and record1. I want them to be [1,][2,]. Is there any function that can do this? How did the `rbind()` function get the index for the row? Does `rbind()` function take the parameter name as the index?
Thanks!

```
> content <-rbind(colNames, record1)
> content
         [,1]   [,2]      [,3]  [,4]  [,5] 
colNames "Draw" "Runners" "Win" "2nd" "3rd"
record1  "1"    "14"      "4"   "0"   "0"  
         [,6]  [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
colNames "4th" "W%" "Q%" "P%" "F%"  ""   
record1  "1"   "29" "29" "29" "36"  ""
```

Comment: Could you post what do you expect? I recommend reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2886003), to learn how to get help with R

Comment: I think it is more about `names(record1) <- colNames`

Comment: `rownames(content) <- NULL`